# I am unable to subscribe/unsubscribe to a subreddit using the reddit API, in iOS

Tags: ios, development-environment, reddit

Can somebody help me with this? I am using an NSURL connection for GET and POST methods. The reddit API is found here: http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_subscribe

I am specifically confused with what the ('sr', 'sr_name') parameter is. Is it an array of some sort? Or do I have to pass either of 'sr' or 'sr_name'?

My current code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.reddit.com/api/subscribe"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    

        request.HTTPBody = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"api_type=json&action=%@&uh=%@&sr=%@", @"sub", modhashString, SubredditTitle] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    
    
    NSURLResponse *response;
    
    NSError *error;
    
    NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    
    if (!error) {
        

        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:POSTReply
                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                              error:nil];
        
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
        
        NSMutableArray *temp = [[json objectForKey:@"json"] objectForKey:@"errors"];
        
        if ([temp count] > 0){
            
            for (int i = 0; i<[temp count]; i++) {
                
                
                NSArray *temp2 = [[NSArray alloc] init];
                temp2 = [temp objectAtIndex:i];
                
                NSLog(@"Contains errors %@", temp2);
                
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[temp2 objectAtIndex:1] message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@":/" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                
                [alert show];
                
            }
        }
        else{
            
            
        }
```

Comment: Post the code you have so far

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you could use Runscope to inspect the request data that is being generated and the response you get back. That might help narrow it down.

Comment: Not sure if I'm too late, but `sr` expects a full name, like `t5_blah`, not `funny`.

Comment: @Josh you helped me out. Thanks for including

Comment: how do you get that name ??